# Get a specific string of numbers inside an url

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, url, get

So here we have some url's from same domain:

```
http://example.com/video6757788/sometext 
http://example.com/video24353/someothertext  
http://example.com/video243537786/somedifferenttext  
http://example.com/video759882  
http://example.com/video64353415  
http://example.com/video342432?session=somestring
```

How to get just the numbers part that comes after video in all types of the url's. I'm trying to get the video id's.

First i get the url's, but then how do I get the id's?

```
var url = $('a[href*="example"]');
var id = ???
```

Comment: The output id must be equal as in each url. Example jsfiddle (which i failed): [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xNdNm/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
$('a[href*="example"]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var url = $this.attr("href");
   var id = url.match(/video(\d+)/i)[1]; //retrieve the number following video*
   //logic
})
```

Or if you want to be [fancy with .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr), equivalent would be:

```
 $('a[href*="example"]').attr("href", function(indx, url) {
   var id = url.match(/video(\d+)/i)[1]; //retrieve the number following video*
   //logic
})
```